# Reset enum singleton field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums, singleton

I am using an enum singleton that looks (somewhat) like this:

```
public enum mySingleton{

  INSTANCE;

  private static String myDrink = null;

  public String getMyDrink(boolean isWizard)
  {
    if (myDrink == null)
    {
      if (isWizard)
        myDrink = "Butterbeer";
      else
        myDrink = "Whiskey";
    }
    return myDrink;
  }

 //Some more functionality
 //...
}
```

Now, to test this singleton i have a few tests that use it. But since all the test run one after the other in the same thread, once i run the first test, `myDrink` is set for all the other tests.

I don't like that.

I was thinkin of using an `@After` function and use reflection to do set `myDrink` to null.

Iv'e tried this:

```
Field f = mySingleton.class.getField("myDrink");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(String.class, null);
```

But i get a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`.

How can it be done?

Comment: `f.set(String, null)` looks dodgy to me... I suspect that isn't your *real* code. Can you give a short but *complete* program to demonstrate this? What you're discovering is that singletons are a pain for test, by the way... you might take the hint and stop using mutable singletons :) (Additionally, having a *static* field is a bit bizarre there... why is it static when you've gone to all the trouble of making sure there's only a single *instance*?)

Comment: And using a Boolean rather than a boolean is questionable as well. And if you plan to use this in a multi-thread environment, as your question suggests, then you have serious problems.

Comment: The singleton isn't mine and i can't change it. I've edited the `f.set(String, null)` and the `Boolean`. There's not much i can do with the singleton. I need to be able to test against it.

Comment: Your underlying problem here is that you have mutable static. Remove that and you're laughing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myDrink` field shouldn't be static. Make it a non-static field, and then use

```
f.set(mySingleton.INSTANCE, null);
```

Also, use `getDeclaredField` instead of `getField`. `getField` looks for public fields.

If you can't change it to non-static, then the first argument is ignored, so just use

```
f.set(null, null);
```

Comment: As stated in the question, the singleton isn't mine to change. I can only USE it

Comment: But you also said that you changed the Boolean to boolean !? Anyway, the first argument will be ignored anyway if the field stays static, so it will work.

Comment: There should be no problems because of the static keyword. Reflection works well with static fields as well as non-static ones.

Comment: That is a brilliant answer! Thanks JB.

Answer (score 2):

The [getField()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) method can access only PUBLIC fields. 
Try with [getDeclaredFields()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use null for the first argument in f.set(...), from the [Field.set javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/),

```
If the underlying field is static, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.
```

And as loodakawa said, use getDeclaredField since myDrink is private.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is only used for testing purposes you can add a package local setter. One which is not normally accessible.

```
/* can only be called from tests in the same package */
void resetMyDrink() {
    myDrink = null;
}
```